# Альтернатива в regex, разделение только символами одного типа

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Шаблон `/fred( |\t)+barney/` совпадает с любой строкой, где слова `fred` и `barney` разделяются пробелом, табуляцией или любой их комбинацией. Если мы хотим, чтобы все символы между `fred` и `barney` были одинаковыми, надо использовать шаблон `/fred( +|\t+)barney/`. В этом случае все разделители должны быть одинаковыми: либо только пробелами, либо только табуляциями.

А почему последний шаблон работает именно так и не совпадает со строкой, в которой есть разные пробельные символы? Допустим, мы идем по цепочке из пробелов, в этом случае совпадение с левой частью до черты. Встретили табуляцию, шаблон слева не подходит, зато совпадение найдено с шаблоном справа. Не понимаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вертикальная черта означает ИЛИ. Одновременно может отработать только одна из частей. Как только одна из частей в группе (круглых скобках) полностью совпадает, т.е. захватывает максимально возможное количество подходящих символов (за счет знака `+` после символа) шаблон считается полностью совпавшим и происходит завершение обработки скобок. Повторной работы скобок не происходит, т.к. после самих скобок символов повторения нет.

P.S. ИЛИ работает *абсолютно* аналогично `||` в языке C. В языке C когда одно из условий совпало, остальные условия *не проверяются*. Стоит обратить внимание, что в регулярных выражениях в целом, условие считается совпавшим тогда, когда совпало оно само и совпала остальная часть выражения. Если при совпавшем условии в ИЛИ остальная часть выражения дала сбой, то и условие считается не совпавшим и будут проверены другие альтернативы.

Comment: Смотря какое или. Похоже, вы говорите, что ИЛИ здесь разделительное. А я думал, что здесь ИЛИ как в языке си.

Comment: Последнее замечание помогло разобраться.

Comment: В отличие от языков программирования альтернативы в регулярных выражениях могут проверяться, даже если предыдущие совпали. Пример `к(о|.д)т` на тексте `кодт` первая альтерантива совпала, но не совпало регулярное выражение следуещее за альтернативой, поэтому происходит откат и проверка следующей альтернативы.

Comment: Смысл моих слов в том, что если совпала одна альтернатива - это не значит, что остальные будут проигнорированы. Смысл Ваших слов в **P.S.** - обратный.

Comment: @ReinRaus Нет, смысл тот же. Просто мы с вами по разному воспринимаем понятие "условие совпало". Отразил свое восприятие в тексте ответа.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что альтернатива совпадает либо с одним подвыражением, либо с другим.

```
к(о|и)т
```

совпадает с

```
кот
```

или

```
кит
```

но не

```
коит
```

или

```
киот
```